# resize two elements simultaneously using jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

i have been trying to resize two windows simultaneously but for some reason it doesnt work.
i tried to catch errors but nothing.

Note: i dont want to use jquery resize since it doesnt have a fast inteval for checking resizes

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function _u(e){
    try {
        e.parent('.boss').find('.first').width( e.width() ); //tried with parent('.boss').next('.first') or directy with prev('.first')
    } catch(err){alert(err);}
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".data").each(function(){
        var resizerint;
        $(this).mousedown(function(){
            try {
                var eee = $(this);
                var resizerint = setInterval(function(){
                        try {
                            _u( eee );
                        } catch(err){alert(err);}
                    },10); // i need it 10ms
            } catch(err){alert(err);}

            $('.test').html('<font style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;color:red;"> mouse DOWN </font>');
        }).mouseup(function(){
            try{
                clearInterval(resizerint);
                } catch(err){alert(err);}

            $('.test').html('<font style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;color:green;"> mouse UP </font>');
        });
    });
});
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="boss">
    <div class="first">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="title">ONEEEEE</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <textarea class="data" > ONEEE TEXTY TESTY NJAMMM! </textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="boss">
    <div class="first">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="title">TWOOOOOO</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
        <textarea class="data" > TWOOO TEXTY TESTY NJAMMM! </textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="text"></div>
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

JSFIDDLE (IF YOU SEE , THE BLUE DOESNT RESIZE WHEN MOUSEDOWN at the TEXTAREA )
http://jsfiddle.net/2sfFW/

Comment: what does it do exactly that isn't working as you want? can you post a jsfiddle with an example?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and how much of that isn't working? What precisely are the constraints - what don't you want to use and why?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot too many questions, i edited ,you can see the jsfiddle example

Comment: note that im trying to resize only width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first answer was that there was a missing "$" but it didn't fix the problem.

Got it working to some extent, but you have to click into the text field first before it will initialize. I used your blue version as a visualizer.

The proper jquery traversal is

```
 e.parent().parent('.boss').find('.first')
```

or

```
 e.parents('.boss').find('.first')
```

You have to use the plural version because there are two parent divs above it. Using parent().parent() is more specific but probably not necessary in this case.

http://jsfiddle.net/aQKVD/1/

If you remove the mouseup/mousedown handlers it will initialize at document.ready instead, which I think might be what you want. You don't necessarily need to do the clearing of the variable unless you have some other need for it, since .each() creates a separate instance of the function tied to the specific div in question. Here's a version like that:

http://jsfiddle.net/aQKVD/2/

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't fix it in JSfiddle, but for starters you've left off a "$". I've set up a JSfiddle link so other people can try it. http://jsfiddle.net/aQKVD/

```
function _u(e){
try {
    e.parent('.boss').find('.first').width( e.width() ); //tried with parent('.boss').next('.first') or directly with prev('.first')
    } catch(err){alert(err);}
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   (".data").each(function(){
```

last line should be

```
   $(".data").each(function(){
```

Comment: nope, its not that, doesnt work, added .first{background-color:blue;} to test it but doesnt work , ".first" doesnt resize